# Parse complex string structure into JSON

Tags: python, text-parsing

I'm receiving a string structure from another process that I need to parse.
I'm trying to parse a string structure into JSON.

This structure is a non Json-compliant string: no quotes, no semicolums, no [] ...

```
I1024 14:35:56.638165  623090 receive_app.cc:185] [ObjectDetectionPredictionResult]      {
  current_time {
    seconds: 1666622156
    nanos: 170191872
  }
  identified_boxes {
    normalized_bounding_box {
      xmin: 0.31263816
      ymin: 0.3188397
      width: 0.31359285
      height: 0.40073034
    }
    confidence_score: 0.77292275
    entity {
      label_string: "Boxed packaged goods"
    }
  }
  identified_boxes {
    normalized_bounding_box {
      xmin: 0.31263816
      ymin: 0.3188397
      width: 0.31359285
      height: 0.40073034
    }
    confidence_score: 0.32609925
    entity {
      label_string: "Bagged packaged goods"
    }
  }
  identified_boxes {
    normalized_bounding_box {
      xmin: 0.31200665
      ymin: 0.31988114
      width: 0.3113994
      height: 0.40169
    }
    confidence_score: 0.3159287
    entity {
      label_string: "Media cover"
    }
  }
}
I1024 14:35:57.668101  623090 receivet_app.cc:177] header    {
  capture_time {
    seconds: 1666622157
    nanos: 184556266
  }
  type {
    type_class: "protobuf"
    type_descriptor {
      type: "ObjectDetectionPredictionResult"
    }
  }
  metadata {
  }
  server_metadata {
    offset: 935
    ingest_time {
      seconds: 1666622157
      nanos: 606121000
    }
  }
}
```

for now, I started manually parsing each identified_boxes using **re.finditer()** but it feels cumbersome, not efficient and even less agile:

```
    for sequence in re.finditer('identified_boxes',payload):
        print(f"{sequence.start()} {sequence.end()} {sequence.group(0)}")
        if previous_stop == 0:
            pass
        else:
            box = payload[previous_stop:sequence.start()]
            print(box)
        previous_stop = sequence.end()
```

What better/optimized method would you recommend ?
Would you "enrich" to string to make it Json compliant ? (i.e adding quotes around the keys). Would you process it as is ? Would you use a lib like shlex (if it makes any sense ...)

**[EDIT]**
to clarify my ask: i expect a list/dict of identified_boxes, similar to:

```
{
    "PredictionResult":
      {"current_time": {"seconds":1666622156,"nanos":170191872},
      "identified_boxes":
        [{"normalized_bounding_box":  
            {"xmin": 0.31263816,
            "ymin": 0.3188397,
            "width": 0.31359285,
            "height": 0.40073034}
        },
        {"normalized_bounding_box":  
            {"xmin": 0.31263816,
            "ymin": 0.3188397,
            "width": 0.31359285,
            "height": 0.40073034}
      }]

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can change the sender so it sends something in a more reasonable format like JSON?

Comment: If not, see [Parsing in Python](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/)

Comment: what is the type of  `payload`? and what exactly do you need to get from this `payload`? all `identified_boxes` and that's it?

Comment: there is actually 2 pretty json compliant dictionaries, all you need to do is to get rid of this `I1024 14:35:56.638165  623090 receive_app.cc:185] [ObjectDetectionPredictionResult]    ` (if you don't need it) and turn the dict after into a string and after that string object is json copmliant one

Comment: Sad that the parsing link above doesn't mention `pygments`. If tasked with this, I would build a RegexLexer for it.

Comment: unfortunately, sender format is out of my hands ...
@DmitriyNeledva, I would need the identified_boxes as a [] with all the childs as key value pairs

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the link - Super interesting. I'll read through and check if I find a suitable parser

Comment: you can get payload's class by `print(type(payload))`

Answer (score 0):

something like this comes to mind, does it suits you?

```
# I assume that `payload` is str class or can be turned into str class 
payload = """I1024 14:35:56.638165  623090 receive_app.cc:185] [ObjectDetectionPredictionResult]      {
  current_time {
    seconds: 1666622156
    nanos: 170191872
  }
  identified_boxes {
    normalized_bounding_box {
      xmin: 0.31263816
      ymin: 0.3188397
      width: 0.31359285
      height: 0.40073034
    }
    confidence_score: 0.77292275
    entity {
      label_string: "Boxed packaged goods"
    }
  }
  identified_boxes {
    normalized_bounding_box {
      xmin: 0.31263816
      ymin: 0.3188397
      width: 0.31359285
      height: 0.40073034
    }
    confidence_score: 0.32609925
    entity {
      label_string: "Bagged packaged goods"
    }
  }
  identified_boxes {
    normalized_bounding_box {
      xmin: 0.31200665
      ymin: 0.31988114
      width: 0.3113994
      height: 0.40169
    }
    confidence_score: 0.3159287
    entity {
      label_string: "Media cover"
    }
  }
}
I1024 14:35:57.668101  623090 receivet_app.cc:177] header    {
  capture_time {
    seconds: 1666622157
    nanos: 184556266
  }
  type {
    type_class: "protobuf"
    type_descriptor {
      type: "ObjectDetectionPredictionResult"
    }
  }
  metadata {
  }
  server_metadata {
    offset: 935
    ingest_time {
      seconds: 1666622157
      nanos: 606121000
    }
  }
}
"""




import re

pattern= r'''identified_boxes {|label_string:.*"
    }
  }'''

seq = list(re.finditer(pattern,payload))
    
for i in range(0,len(seq)-1,2):
    print(payload[seq[i].start():seq[i+1].end()])




# output:
# identified_boxes {
#     normalized_bounding_box {
#       xmin: 0.31263816
#       ymin: 0.3188397
#       width: 0.31359285
#       height: 0.40073034
#     }
#     confidence_score: 0.77292275
#     entity {
#       label_string: "Boxed packaged goods"
#     }
#   }
# identified_boxes {
#     normalized_bounding_box {
#       xmin: 0.31263816
#       ymin: 0.3188397
#       width: 0.31359285
#       height: 0.40073034
#     }
#     confidence_score: 0.32609925
#     entity {
#       label_string: "Bagged packaged goods"
#     }
#   }
# identified_boxes {
#     normalized_bounding_box {
#       xmin: 0.31200665
#       ymin: 0.31988114
#       width: 0.3113994
#       height: 0.40169
#     }
#     confidence_score: 0.3159287
#     entity {
#       label_string: "Media cover"
#     }
#   }
```

Comment: That's a start but won't be enough. I need to parse the details to make use of the data, i.e as a dict or list. I added those expectations as well as an example output in the question